# FFMPEG - Partial fade effects

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm having difficulty achieving the desired fading effect for the logo in my video using ffmpeg.

I would like to make a 3-second video ([here is an example](https://local-banners.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/video/video-with-partial-fade-effects.mp4)) with:

- A background image (300x350 jpeg file)
- A logo overlaid in the center of the background image (100x40 png file)
- And I would like the logo to fade in and out with the following opacity timeline:

1. At 0 second, the opacity is 0.5
2. At 1 second, the opacity is 1
3. At 2 second, the opacity is 0.2
4. At 3 second, the opacity is 1.

As the fade filter does not support any target or source value (it is a full fade from 0 to 1 or the reverse), I cannot use it.

*For example:
Here is how to add an overlay with a fully fade IN (between 0 to 1s) and a fully fade OUT (from 2s to 3s):*

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.jpeg -framerate 30 -loop 1 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0]format=rgba,scale=300:250[o];[1]format=rgba,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=2:d=1:alpha=1[i];[o][i]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" -c:v libx264 -t 3 output.mp4
```

I also tried the `geq` filter with a `lerp` operation but it is quite difficult to write (and the result I got is wrong, I may have a problem with the `lerp` operator):

```
ffmpeg -i background.jpeg -framerate 30 -loop 1 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=300:250[o];[1]format=yuva420p,geq=a='if(lt(T\,1)\,lerp(0\,1\,T)*0.5*alpha(X\,Y)\,if(lt(T\,2)\,lerp(1\,2\,T)*0.2*-alpha(X\,Y),lerp(2\,3\,T)*alpha(X\,Y)))':r='r(X\,Y)'[i];[o][i]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" -c:v libx264 -t 3 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 0 output.mp4
```

I also found that scripting filters (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide#ScriptingFilters) are also available for the `geq` filter but I haven't found a way to use it for that specific use case.

What would be the more appropriate approach to handle that kind of effect?

Comment: try `geq=a='if(lt(T,1),lerp(0.5,1,T)*alpha(X,Y),if(lt(T,2),lerp(1,0.2,T-1)*alpha(X,Y),lerp(0.2,1,T-2)*alpha(X,Y)))':r='r(X,Y)'`

Comment: Thank you, that works. However, do you know of a simpler way to achieve this effect? Maybe the scripting filter way?

Comment: u can try: `...[1]format=gbrap,
split=3[s1][s2][s3];
[s1]geq=a='lerp(0.5,1,T)*alpha(X,Y)':r='r(X,Y)'[v1];
[s2]geq=a='lerp(1,0.2,T)*alpha(X,Y)':r='r(X,Y)'[v2];
[s3]geq=a='lerp(0.2,1,T)*alpha(X,Y)':r='r(X,Y)'[v3];
[v1][v2][v3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[i];...` and insert `-t 1` before logo.png